# Move-Item from/to unc path length limit?

Tags: powershell

A script that was working is now failing with what seem to be very long file names when im trying to move them.  So as a test, I thought I would debug and found the case where the error is being thrown.  On the line that executes a Move-Item, I get this kind of error

> is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a  path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
>   path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:233

Question:
With Move-Item -Path ... -Destination  is there a limit on the length of either the Path or the Destination?  Considering that these will be unc paths, but its the file names in this case that are 100-200 characters long, in one case a 240 character filename.

Comment: The character limit (260) includes the whole path not just the filename - you can map a drive lower down the path to get around this, or on a more recent Windows OS, there is a registry setting to enable long filenames and a Powershell switch of -LiteralPath to get the job done.